# Kubuntu not all external monitors are working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

a little while ago after updating some packages KDE has stopped functioning, all I got was a black screen, but I was able to go to terminal with ctrl+alt+f2. After reinstalling KDE (not the entire OS but just the packages) I was able to get it working again. Before that I did try to reinstall amdgpu driver but it failed. (I'm using a laptop with ryzen cpu (radeon graphics) + nvidia rtx 3070)

KDE is functionally normally, except 2 out of 3 external screens are no longer working (they worked fine before). I can only get the internal screen and 1 external monitor working.
1 monitor is connected through HDMI, 2 others are displayport using a usb-c to display port adapter. The screen that's working is 1 of the display port screens.
I tried removing kscreen settings and rebooting, but this is not working.

Here's my xrandr output with all monitors connected, I have enabled 2 external monitors but only 1 is working. The others (built in and external monitor) are disabled. (If I enable the 3rd external monitor I only get half a screen..)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5119 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1600    165.00 +  60.00 +
   1920x1200    165.00  
   1920x1080    165.00  
   1600x1200    165.00  
   1680x1050    165.00  
   1280x1024    165.00  
   1440x900     165.00  
   1280x800     165.00  
   1280x720     165.00  
   1024x768     165.00  
   800x600      165.00  
   640x480      165.00  
DisplayPort-0 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1440     60.00  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    24.00    23.98    25.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     59.95  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.95  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-7 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1-8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      50.00    59.94  
   1152x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
eDP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  2560x1440 (0x67) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1200 (0x72) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080 (0x74) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x7c) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x7d) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x7e) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1152x864 (0x81) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x82) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x83) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x86) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x88) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x8d) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x8e) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x90) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x92) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x93) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x97) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x73) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x900 (0x7f) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  800x600 (0x8f) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
```

hwinfo:

```
hwinfo --gfxcard --short
graphics card:                                                  
                       nVidia GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]
                       ATI VGA compatible controller

Primary display adapter: #18
```

gpus:

```
sudo lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
34:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] (rev c8)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Rembrandt [Radeon 680M]
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

amdgpu-install output:

```
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                              
Hit:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                                            
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cappelikan/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                 
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                               
Hit:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease                                          
Hit:7 https://repo.fig.io/apt stable InRelease                                                               
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                             
Get:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease [5.931 B]                               
Ign:10 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                            
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease   
Hit:12 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release
Hit:13 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.6/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:14 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.6 focal InRelease
Fetched 5.931 B in 1s (5.671 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic is already the newest version (6.2.0-23.23).
linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 but it is not installable
 libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 but it is not installable
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but it is not installable
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but it is not installable
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: xorg-video-abi-24 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  525.116.04  Thu Apr 27 17:56:37 UTC 2023
GCC version:
```

What can I do to get all external monitors working again?

I also tried to see if I could switch the driver using GNOME's Software & Updates 'additional drivers' tab, but it's stuck on 'continue using manually installed driver' with all other options greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

ended up fixing it with

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I was hesistant using this earlier, because I've used it before and resulted in black screens. But this time it seems it fixed my nvidia driver the easy way. :)

after this the external monitors were working, but still were slow with rendering (only rendering properly when my mouse was at that screen). I fixed this with the command

```
nvidia-settings
```

then at 'PRIME Profiles' switch to NVIDIA (Performance Mode). After a reboot everything worked normally.

when running amdgpu-install it still shows the sam error (not finding libffi7, but I can't seem to find how to install this package). If anyone can clarify why this happens and how to fix (if I should fix it) that would be great.